# Why Yeoman is not present after i installed it?

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I try to install yeoman but it's not working :

```
npm install -g yo 

/Users/john/npm/bin/yo-complete -> /Users/john/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/completion/index.js
/Users/john/npm/bin/yo -> /Users/john/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js
> yo@2.0.1 postinstall /Users/john/npm/lib/node_modules/yo

> yodoctor

Yeoman Doctor

Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ Node.js version
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
Everything looks all right!
+ yo@2.0.1
updated 1 package in 11.935s
```

john$ `yo --version`

-bash: /usr/local/bin/yo: No such file or directory

Comment: I don't know why but yeoman was installed in /Users/john/npm/lib/node_modules/yo and not in /usr/local/bin. I added node modules in path and that works

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `yo` installation log.

The `yo` binary should be at `/Users/john/npm/bin/yo`. You can try doing a `/Users/john/npm/bin/yo --version` to confirm this.

If it responded accordingly and your machine is not seeing `yo` on `yo --version`. Then it is usually something to do with your `PATH` environment variable.

You'll have to make sure that the directory `/Users/john/npm/bin/` is part of the `$PATH` environment variable, otherwise your machine will not know where to look for the `yo` binary.

Comment: $ /Users/john/npm/yo --version 
-bash: /Users/davykiala/npm/yo: No such file or directory

Comment: I add /Users/john/npm/yo in $NODE_PATH but the command yo 
-bash: yo: command not found

Comment: `PATH` not `NODE_PATH`

Comment: I try now when i run yo --version i don't have neither error nor the version

Comment: Assuming you're on linux you can do a `which yo` to confirm that the machine is invoking the correct `yo` binary. It should be using the one you installed. Which is from `/Users/john/npm/bin/yo`. If it is using the right one then you are on the right track.